# Get-ADUser Powershell Parameter

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to write a little Tool like a little CLI where I can get Informations out of our AD-Domain.
I have that function (listed below) which works but I want it not to ask me the Parameter in the second place. The Goal is to let the Tool run in a Loop where I can type the Function-Shortcuts with given Parameter like "Username"

ListUserInformation -Username "Firstname, Lastname" (Something like that.)
I tryed double and single quotes but it keeps asking in the next line about a Username.
Can some1 help me with that? Here is the Function:

```
    function ListUserInformation {
        [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$Username
    )
        
        $target = $Username
        $x = Get-ADUser -Filter "CN -like '$target'"  -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties CN,Title,SamAccountName,emailaddress,officephone | Out-String
            Select-Object CN,Title,SamAccountName,emailaddress,officephone
        write-host $x }
```

Comment: It works fine on my end. Are you sure you reloaded your function in the correct console after modifying it?

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Thomas, could you tell me what exactly you typed in?
Imagine there is a Loop waiting for Input like lui (for ListUserInformation).
and I want to give it the Username straight away like:
lui -Username "Firstname, Lastname"
I am kinda new so could you tell me what you mean with "reloaded"?
I saved the Testscript and started it from a new opened PS Console.

Comment: Remove `| Out-String` and also make a second parameter for the `$SearchBase` variable.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, remove `Out-String`. Also, your function could be more versatile if you add a second (optional) parameter `$SearchBase`.

`Write-Host` just outputs to console and is not a return value of the function.
Either use the `return` keyword or leave it out alltogether.

Something like this:

```
function ListUserInformation {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [String]$Username,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [String]$SearchBase = 'CN=SomeWhere,CN=Users,DC=Company,DC=com'  # insert your predefined OU searchbase here
    )
    $Properties = 'CN','Title','SamAccountName','EmailAddress','OfficePhone'
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SearchBase)) {
        Get-ADUser -Filter "CN -like '$Username'" -Properties $Properties |
        Select-Object $Properties
    }
    else {
        Get-ADUser -Filter "CN -like '$Username'" -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties $Properties |
        Select-Object $Properties
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$x = ListUserInformation -Username 'Pa1n4ndt3rr0r'
```

Comment: The Searchbase is set but not shown here as Its confidential. Please check out my Comment on Pba´s Answer as I described my Main Issue better there. Thanks alot for your response!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change one minor thing.
`Write-Host` doesn't give you an output that you can use in follow up commands.

`Return` on the other hands does.

```
function ListUserInformation {
    [CmdletBinding()]
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$Username
)
    
    $target = $Username
    $x = Get-ADUser -Filter "CN -like '$target'"  -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties CN,Title,SamAccountName,emailaddress,officephone | Out-String
        Select-Object CN,Title,SamAccountName,emailaddress,officephone
return $x }
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: That works, yes. But my Main Problem is not solved, maybe I did not describe it well enough. I want a consistant Loop waiting for my Input. This Function (ListUserInformation) is only one of many which I want to run. I want to Start the script and it should run in that Loop which waits for the Input and if the Input is as following:
ListUserInformation -Username "Firstname, Lastname" it should recognize that it has to run the ListUserInformation function with -Username "Firstname, Lastname" as its parameter for the Get-ADUser function to work.I want all in one line Sorry for bad English ^^

Comment: so you want the above script to loop and wait for your input after every loop?

Comment: Basically yes. It should always wait for my Input and should recognize which Function and Parameters it gets within the same one Lane as I described above